Minifying Cartthrob /store/cart.js
I am using Cart Throb and I am just wondering what is the best way to minify the /store/cart.js file obviously this has some expression engine templating within this file so when I use my normal minifier it doesn't work.
Thanks,
John

You could try using an online tool to manually minify the code then replace the original version. Bear in mind when you update Cartthrob it will probably replace it with a new non minified version.
The version of that file I have is about 9kb so any saving is minimal in the grand scheme of things if you're minifying the rest of the site.
